# What is '^' operator used in C other than to check if two numbers are equal?

Tags: c, gcc

What are the purposes of `^` operator used in C other than to check if two numbers are equal? Also, why is it used for equality in stead of `==` in the first place?

Comment: It's the bitwise exclusive-or operator. Probably somebody used it as a  premature optimization of comparison, assuming the bitwise operation would be faster than `==`.

Comment: Please provide the code example.

Comment: Really?   This kind of question is 100%, trivially, Googleable....

Comment: sounds like something you might use for code obfuscation.

Comment: @abelenky I don't agree - yes, you could google for that the operator is called, and what it does, but the question is: 'what is it used for' (i.e. what good is it?) several posters have answered that it can be used to detect which bits are different, it is used in cryptography, it is used for toggling bit flags, etc. I don't think this is *quite* as trivial a question as it sounds, and IMO, does not deserve to be voted < 0… (When I first learned C, [back when the world was black and white and dinosaurs roamed the earth,] it was not obvious to me why I would ever use XOR…)

Comment: Without an example of what you're asking about this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 6):

The `^` operator is the bitwise XOR operator. Although I have never seen it's use for checking equaltity.

`x ^ y` will evaluate to `0` exatly when `x == y`.

Comment: At least in Assembly programming, XOR is used all the time as a means to check if two values are the same.  XOR them together, then JUMP IF ZERO, or JUMP IF NOT ZERO....

Comment: @abelenky Why is that? Is `==` bad for assembly programming?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Because there is no `==` instruction.

Comment: @Jite sure there is, it's usually called something like `CMP`

Comment: XOR is faster than a CMP. That's good coding in assembly. Doing it in C code is not. Let the compiler make those judgements.

Comment: @Alnitak However `==` is literally different from `CMP` even if they do the same thing... There is no instruction literally called `==`.

Comment: @FredLarson citation required.  A `CMP` or `XOR` instruction should AFAIK complete in the same number of cycles.  Strictly speaking a `CMP` requires slightly more logic because it effectively does a subtraction (and hence requires that the carry bit trickles) but that's still all done within one cycle.

Comment: this answer says what the XOR operator *is* -- it would be nice to more properly address the question of: what is it used for? (i.e. in what contexts do you typically use a bitwise XOR?)

Comment: @Alnitak: It probably goes back to my college days working on the 8086. Seems to me the XOR was a few cycles faster than SUB or CMP. All the more reason not to do this in C.

Comment: i386 also implements the `test` instruction which is an xor that does not store the result. It is indeed faster on i386 then `cmp`. I have never seen that practice in C though.

Comment: @FredLarson actually http://zsmith.co/ says that `CMP` is sometimes faster than `XOR` (and never slower).

Comment: @SergeyL. yup, avoiding that write cycle certainly helps.

Comment: @Jite You can't argue that - saying there's no instruction named `==` is the same as pointing out that there is no C operator written `xor`.

Comment: @Alnitak:  Yeah, my cycle time information may be incorrect or at least outdated (it was over 25 years ago I was in college, after all). But I think it only amplifies my main point: the programmer is not smarter than the compiler writer. Don't do "clever" tricks like this.

Comment: @Alnitak Seriously, abelenky explained about comparing with XOR and the guy specifically asks if `==` bad for assembly programming`? I answer that `==` doesn't exist.

Comment: @FredLarson yup, absolutely!

Comment: @Alnitak: In typical modern processors, there is usually a form of XOR instruction that writes its output to a specified registers, but a CMP instruction usually writes its output to a special register to hold comparison results. Both of these tie up a register for a period of time, preventing other instructions from using the same register until the XOR or CMP instruction is completed. Even though the actual XOR or CMP computation may execute in a single cycle, modern processors divide instruction execution into several stages: loading, decoding, dispatching, waiting for data, computing,…

Comment: … writing results, and completing. So even a fast instruction can tie up a register for a while. The general registers are usually “renamed” inside the processor; it has many more physical registers than architecturally visible registers and maps program names like R0, R1, R2,… to internal registers. So it can use this renaming to partially free up the general register used by the XOR. However, typically the special registers used for comparison results are not renamed or there are fewer of them.

Comment: Additionally, XORs may be chained with other results more easily. The computation `A == 1 && B == 2 && C == 3` may be turned into several comparisons and branches by a compiler, and branches are bad for performance in typical modern processors (since the processors are trying to load instructions in advance and start execution before they know the results of prior instructions). The same result can be achieved with `((A ^ 1) | (B ^ 2) | (C ^ 3)) == 0`, which is usually compiled to instructions with a single branch.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'd still rather write `A == 1 && B == 2 && C == 3`. It's much easier to read, and I believe the optimizer is likely to transform it into XORs if it thinks that would be faster.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sounds like something that the compiler should handle, rather than the programmer.

Comment: @Lundin: “Should” and “does” are different.

Comment: @FredLarson: Sometimes engineering is not about what you would rather do but about what must be done to achieve the goal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes. But before you write obscure code, verify through disassembly that 1) the compiler actually does a poor job and 2) that your version is better.

Answer (score 2):

`^` is a bit-wise [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_XOR_.22.5E.22) operator in C. It can be used in bits toggling and to swap two numbers;

```
x^=y, y^=x, x^=y;
```

and can be used to find max of two numbers;

```
int max(int x, int y)
{
      return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); 
}
```

Comment: OP asked what it is used for, not what the operator does, which can be trivially found online (i.e. the question asks specifically about applications of the operator) If you have never had to do any bit-manipulation, it's not obvious why the bitwise XOR operation is useful.

Comment: @JVMATL; Sorry. My bad. Edited my answer.

Comment: Much improved! I never saw it used for a max function before. Looks inefficient, but interesting nonetheless. There's probably an equivalent min() function, but I'm not a good enough bit-twiddler to find it without a lot of experimenting.. :)

Comment: @JVMATL; Actually that was asked in an interview! :)

Comment: Has anyone in the world yet managed to come up with a rationale of why you would swap numbers using XOR? I can't think of a single case where it would be more effective than the readable version with a temporary variable. Nor can I think of any version involving XOR that does not need to allocate at least one temporary variable in the actual machine code. Can anyone prove me wrong with some disassembly?

Comment: @Lundin; I never use these techniques in practice. But these type of question are common in interviews.

Comment: There are so many bad interviews... "Lets ask him about something that he will never have use for at the job we are offering."

Answer (score 2):

It can be used to selectively flip bits. (e.g. to toggle the value of bit #3 in an integer, you can say `x = x ^ (1<<3)`  or, more compactly, `x = x^0x08` or even `x^=8`. (although now that I look at it, the last form looks like some sort of obscene emoticon and should probably be avoided. :)

It should *never* be used in a test for equality (in C), except in tricky code meant to test undergrads' understanding of the `^` operator. (In assembly, there may be speed advantages on some architectures.)

Comment: _It should never be used in a test for equality_,...  assembly programmers would likely disagree. (there is no `==` instruction).  But +1 for the obscene emoticon comment anyway.

Comment: :) thanks. I'm not sure what assembly programmers would have to disagree about though, the OP asked about uses *in C*. But I'll clarify that in my reply.

Answer (score 2):

The XOR operator is used in cryptography (en- and decrypting text using a pseudo-random bit stream), random number generators (like the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)) and in [inline-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) and other [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html):

```
 int a = ...;
 int b = ...;

 // swap a and b
 a ^= b;
 b ^= a;
 a ^= b;
```

(useful if you don't have space for another variable like on CPUs with few registers).

Answer (score 2):

`^` is the Bitwise XOR.

A bitwise operation operates on one or more bit patterns or binary numerals at the level of their individual bits. It is a fast, primitive action directly supported by the processor, and is used to manipulate values for comparisons and calculations. (source: [Bitwise Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation))

The XOR Operator has two operands and it returns `1` if only one of the operands is set to `1`.

So a Bitwise XOR Operation of two numbers is the resulting of these bit by bit operations.

For exemple:

```
00000110 // A = 6

00001010 // B = 10

00001100 // A ^ B = 12
```

Comment: +1 for showing the effects of the XOR on two ints - but can you expand on the *applications* of the XOR - that was, I think , the gist of his (her?) question.

Comment: The OP is thinking the operator `^` is equivalent to `==`.

Comment: no, he's asking what else is it used for besides a test for equality? (he probably saw some code where they test `if ((a^b)==0)`

Comment: Advantages of the Bitwise operations are described in the first Paragraph (fast, primitive action directly supported by the processor...).

Answer (score 1):

It it's the exclusive or operator. It will do bitwise exclusive or on the two arguments. If the numbers are equal, this will result in 0, while if they're not equal, the bits that differed between the two arguments will be set.

You generally wouldn't use it inserted of `==`, you would use it only when you need to know which bits are different.

Answer (score 1):

Two real usage examples from an embedded system I worked on:

In a status message generating function, where one of the words was supposed to be a passthrough of an external device's status word. There was an disconnect between the device behavior and the message spec - one thought bit0 meant 'error' while the other thought it meant 'OK'.

```
statuswords[3] = devicestatus ^ 1; //invert B0
```

The 16-bit target processor was terribly slow to branch, so in an inner loop `if (sign(A)!=sign(B) B=0;` was coded as:

```
B*=~(A^B)>>15;
```

which took 4 cycles rather than 8, and does the same thing: sets B to 0 iff the sign bits are different.

Answer (score 0):

in many general cases we might use '^' as a replacement for'==' but that doesn't exactly give the result for being equal or not.Instead - it checks the given variables bit by bit and sets a result for each bit individually and finally displays a result summed up with the resulting bits as a bulk.